# How do I perform a function similar to Windows' Easy Transfer?

Tags: transfer

You know how Windows has the thing where you can plug in a male-male cable into two computers, and then transfer stuff from one system to the other? Is there a way to do that in Linux?

Comment: Is copying the whole home folder not an option? Just beware that, to make your life easier with permissions and such, only copy and paste from users with the same user id. The default user's id is 1000 in Ubuntu, and permissions are associated with this number. That means you can copy all the content from the main user's home folder of a machine to the main user's home folder of another machine and everything will be fine. Then you'll have to reinstall your programs, but at least all the settings and files will be there (don't forget to copy the hidden folders as well).

Comment: @Pablo: How is that related to OP's question?

Comment: @David It wasn't clear whether what's important was copying the files and settings or copying via cable, because, when I looked up what Windows Easy Transfer was, all I saw advertised was the ability to copy everything (cables are not mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

In theory, using avahi you shoud get IP auto setup.

The relevant packages are:

```
avahi-autoipd
avahi-daemon
samba
```

After all of that is installed, you should be able to share a folder in the server computer and find it in the network browser in the client computer.